# Loading TFRecord file in RAM

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset, deep-learning, tfrecord

I have a dataset which is about 50G, and I want to convert it into tfrecord. the tfrecord file will be at least 50G too. So, when I want to read this file, how can it be loaded in RAM? ( RAM<16G)

Comment: Have you tried using a custom hash table so that you can allocate the dataset the way you want?

Comment: Honestly Im trying to convert a part of IMDB dataset to tfrecord format in which is about 50G. im using pascalvoc_to_tfrecords.py. the link is here: 
    https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow/blob/master/datasets/pascalvoc_to_tfrecords.py